# Jasmine - how to unit test a TypeScript class that imports another class with static methods

Tags: typescript, ionic2, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a simple TypeScript class (in my Ionic application), which implements a simple "typed" dictionary...

```
import { Utils } from './utils';

 export class Dictionary<T> {
   constructor(private noCase?: boolean, init?: Array<{ key: string; value:T; }>) {
    ....
   }
}
```

I have written some very simple tests for it...

```
    import { Dictionary } from './dictionary';

    let dictionary : Dictionary<string> = null;
    describe('Dictionary', () => {
         beforeEach(() => {
            dictionary = new Dictionary<string>(true, []);
        });

      it('should have containsKey find a value added', () => {
          dictionary.add("a", "A Val");
          let exists = dictionary.containsKey("a");
          expect(exists).toBeTruthy()
         });
    });
```

When I run the test, I get the following error...

```
        Chrome 60.0.3112 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
      Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__dictionary__.a is not a constructor
      at webpack:///src/shared/utils.ts:19:17 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:77758
    Chrome 60.0.3112 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
      Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__dictionary__.a is not a constructor
      at webpack:///src/shared/utils.ts:19:17 <- test-config/karma-test-shim.js:77758
    Chrome 60.0.3112 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.422 secs / 0 secs)
    webpack: Compiling...
```

My problem is the `Utils` class that I have in the class being tested (the `Dictionary`)

This `Utils` class just has a bunch of static "utils" methods, (string compares, formatting, etc)

```
    import * as moment from 'moment';
    import 'moment-duration-format';
    import * as _ from 'lodash';
    import { TranslateService } from 'ng2-translate';
    import { Dictionary } from './dictionary';
    .....


    export class Utils {
      public static guard(obj: any, name: string): void {
        if (obj == null || obj == undefined)
          throw (name + " must not be null!");
      }

       public static guardS(s: string, name: string): void {
        if (this.isNullorEmptyOrWhiteSpace(s))
          throw (name + " must not be null or empty!");
       }

      ...  etc
      }
```

The only thing I use in the `Dictionary` class from the the `Utils` is the static `guard` method (that is shown above).

Is there a way I can test my class that includes this other class with the static methods? Can I mock this class's static methods?

While the above class is trivial, I have other stuff I would like to test, that also includes this static `Utils` class.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add a spy to mock the guard method in Utils class.

```
spyOn(Utils, 'guard').and.returnValue(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. My actual problem was a bit of a circular reference, I referenced the class under test in the imported static class, ie I had import { Dictionary } from './dictionary'; in the Utils class